# Retrieve byte array from sqlite but while decoding it to bimap,bitmap shows null and bitmap not set to imageview

Tags: android

For Insert Image

```
     db = openOrCreateDatabase("SaveRetriveDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SaveRetriveTbl (IMG_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,ImgTxt VARCHAR,StoreImg BLOB);");db.execSQL("INSERT INTO  SaveRetriveTbl(ImgTxt,StoreImg)VALUES('txt','" + imageInByte + "')");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

here Image is in Byte Array Format

For View image

```
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("SaveRetriveDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SaveRetriveTbl (IMG_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,ImgTxt VARCHAR,StoreImg BLOB);");

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT  StoreImg FROM SaveRetriveTbl where IMG_ID=2", null);

    if(c!=null){
    c.moveToFirst();
    do{
    InByte=c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("StoreImg"));
    Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(InByte,0,InByte.length);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
    if (b != null) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"bitmap is not null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"bitmap is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }while(c.moveToNext());
```

while retrieving image it shows only byte code but it can't decode this into bitmap.